# Oracle Apex foreign key to form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am building an application using oracle apex 4.0.

I have created a foreign key in a table and I need to fetch all the available foreign keys also some of the associated attributes into form fields so I could select one from the available options(drop down kind of thing). How can i establish this?

I hope I have been clear.

Comment: Not sure about your terminology - you don't "create a foreign key in a table", but you can create a foreign key relationship from one table to another. What do you mean by "fetch all the available foreign keys"?

Comment: Ok. In simpler words. There is a form in which i would want the user to enter the primary key of some other table using a drop down. And then store the entire form as a record in other table.